# How to remove spikes from boundaries in ListContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, smoothing

I have a table with three columns, that is of the form {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2}....}.

I have done a ListContourPlot with it.

But the contour boundaries have spikes in it. What might be the reason and the possible solution? I want to make the boundaries smooth.

```
ListContourPlot[TRScanF[[All, {2, 1, 3}]], 
 PlotRange -> {{-9, -5}, {0.01, 0.075}}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 20], 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[
    "", Black, 
    FontSize -> 30], 
   Style["", Black, 
    FontSize -> 30]}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Larger, Bold], 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {3, 7}}], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Contours -> {3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, 
 PlotLabel -> " ", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}, 
    LegendLabel -> "", 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, FontSize -> 25}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 430}], {1.02, 0.6}], AspectRatio -> 4/5, 
 ImageSize -> 800, InterpolationOrder -> 500000]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: Have you tried changing the number of PlotPoints ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on exactly how smooth you need them, but if you decrease the maximum number of plot points allowed, the contours will become smoother. The problem is that your data really is that rough and it's trying to draw the contours around where they're supposed to be.

Also, `InterpolationOrder -> 500000` doesn't really make sense. Generally, I can't imagine a situation where you would want to be outside of 0 to 5 (and more commonly 0 to 3). Look up `InterpolationOrder` in the documentation system to see what it does.

In the code, the only two things I change are `MaxPlotPoints -> 20` and I remove `InterpolationOrder -> 500000`. It will default to 3.

```
ListContourPlot[
 TRScanF[[All, {2, 1, 3}]],
 PlotRange -> {{-9, -5}, {0.01, 0.075}},
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 20], 
 FrameLabel -> {Style[
    "Log[\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(3\)]\)]", Black, 
    FontSize -> 30], 
   Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(g\), \(BL\)]\)", Black, 
    FontSize -> 30]}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Larger, Bold], 
 ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"Rainbow", {3, 7}}],
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
 Contours -> {3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
 MaxPlotPoints -> 20,
 PlotLabel -> " ", 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}, 
    LegendLabel -> "Log[\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(R\)]\) (GeV)]", 
    LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, FontSize -> 25}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {20, 430}], {1.02, 0.6}], AspectRatio -> 4/5,
 ImageSize -> 800]
```

Comment: The problem is solved. Can you please edit and remove the plot (for copyright issues)? It would be highly appreciated if you do so. Please.

Comment: @surujjd No problem, I’ve removed the plot.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @surujjd, you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of the [licensing terms](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing) for using Stack Exchange. No one is obligated to remove these images on your behalf.